# Jquery fade out all other elms on hover, don't fade back in until mouse off all elms for a period of time

Tags: jquery, fade

I've got a page full of `article`s, with margins between them, wrapped in a `<div id="shell">` and am trying to create an effect where if you hover over an article all the others fade out. That's fairly simple to do but when you move from one article to another everything else fades in and out again. Instead of letting all the articles fade back in by leaving the `#shell` I want them to only fade back when the mouse has been in the shell but not on an article for 500ms as the shell takes up the entire window.

```
$('article').hover(function() {
    if ($('body').hasClass('hover')) {
        $(this).fadeTo(100,1);
    }
    else {
        $('body').addClass('hover');
        $('article').not(this).fadeTo(300, 0.6);
    }
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(300,0.6);
    checkandfade();
});

function checkandfade() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
            if (e.target.id == 'shell' && $('body').hasClass('hover')){
                $('article').stop(true,true).fadeTo(100, 1);
                $('body').removeClass('hover');
            }
        });
    },500);
};
```

That's what I have so far but I don't think the timeout is working.. It occasionally works but mostly fades the rest back in then out again. Am I going about this completely the wrong way or is there just a glitch in my code? If you have any ideas or simpler solutions I'd love some feedback.

Follow my feeble progress [here](http://archetypiccurator.tumblr.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
var timeout = 0;
$('article').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).addClass('artHovered').fadeTo(100,1);
    fadeOutArticles();
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('artHovered');
    fadeOutArticles();
});
function fadeOutArticles(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $('article').not('.artHovered').fadeTo(300,0.6, function(){
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            if($('article.artHovered').length==0){
                $('article').stop(true,true).fadeTo(100, 1);
            }
        }, 500);
    });     
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code, I assume this is what you were trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past (albeit on a menu) by using the hoverIntent plugin. This lets you set a mouseenter and mouseleave function and also specify a timeout as to precisely when they should be triggered. You can also combine this with boolean variable checks, i.e. set something to true on mouseenter and false on mouseleave AFTER the timeout (in effect deferring it to a later time). You can then check this bool in different event functions to decide whether you want to do something or not.

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html